# MySQL Insert Query Randomly Takes a Long Time

Tags: php, mysql, performance, session, innodb

I am using MySQL to manage session data for my PHP application. When testing the app, it is usually very quick and responsive. However, seemingly randomly the response will stall before finally completing after a few seconds. I have narrowed the problem down to the session write query which looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Session VALUES('lvg0p9peb1vd55tue9nvh460a7', '1275704013', '') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sessAccess='1275704013',sessData='';
```

The slow query log has this information:

```
Query_time: 0.524446  Lock_time: 0.000046 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
```

This happens about 1 out of every 10 times. The query usually only takes ~0.0044 sec.

The table is InnoDB with about 60 rows. sessId is the primary key with a BTREE index.

Since this is accessed on every page view, it is clearly not an acceptable execution time. Why is this happening?

**Update:** Table schema is: sessId:varchar(32), sessAccess:int(10), sessData:text

Comment: What type of column is sessData? Please provide the whole schema for your table.

Comment: Describe your test environment (Processor, RAM, Disk, free space on disk, what else is running on the box that might compete for CPU/RAM/Disk). Sometimes random performance problems are environmental.

Comment: The application is on a VPS hosting plan with approx 300 MB of RAM. It is a CentOS server running typically minimal web software.

Answer (score 2):

Note that inserting into the middle of a BTree index does require a release of the page quite often, and a rebuild of a portion of the index. For a clustered index (your primary key is probably your clustered index), the actual row data must be moved too when the page is rebuilt.

If the row data is large, it will take some time.

For your case, it might be best to use an autoincrement primary key, and just use a unique index on sessId, so you're not inserting records into the middle of a clustered index.

Answer (score 2):

Reproduce the problem on something that isn't a VM, then you can complain.

Virtual machines, particularly ones shared with arbitrary third parties, have behaviour which cannot be relied upon, in my experience.

In all likelihood, innoDB is trying to do a fdatasync(). This needs to do some actual physical IO, which is blocked by another task on the host box (perhaps another VM) doing something. If you don't control them, you cannot predict what its behaviour will be.

If the sessions table does not need to be persistent across database shutdowns, consider ENGINE=Memory.

If you have no strong data durability requirement, then reduce the innodb durability settings (but this will affect the entire server not just the table)

Comment: I see your point about possible VM contention. Even if resources are guaranteed, there is only one hard drive head per machine.

I did consider using the MEMORY engine, but according to the MySQL documentation; "MEMORY tables use a fixed-length row storage format.". So, that probably isn't the best way to store binary data that varies in size, especially if the majority of entries will be empty.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the problem on a non-VM? If you can, then more investigation needs to be done. In general, performance, latency, etc are not as good on a VM as real hardware, and are much less predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using a surrogate autoincrement key as suggested, but still had problems with speed when executing the query.

Solution was to switch the table's engine to MyISAM which does quicker inserts.

Comment: How come a MYISAM table does insert quicker than INNODB table? MyISAM engine is best for reading, not for writing.